# Firebase - Delete a node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an ionic+angular+firebase application.
I am unable to delete a node from my firebase collection. I have an html view which displays a list of items from an array(using ng-repeat). This is how my view looks:

```
test@testmail.com : 23
fire@firemail.com : 784
```

I have a delete button which allows the user to delete an item from the array and this in turn should delete the object from my firebase collection. I want to order the collection using the eventid and then delete the node with bill:23 and email:"test@testmail.com"

```
Bill
-KMhWUkwDFwlRvqv0kDG
  bill: 23
  email: "test@testmail.com"
  eventid: **42539660**

-KN0_OUYJf_XQJSLPgmi
 bill: 784
 email: "fire@firemail.com"
 eventid: **42539660**
```

I am able to get all the bills with a specific eventid using the query:

```
var id = 42539660;
billref.orderByChild('eventid').equalTo(id).on("value", function (snapshot) {
}
```

but i am not sure how to proceed from here to delete the specific node. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the node that your query matches:

```
var id = 42539660;
billref.orderByChild('eventid').equalTo(id).on("value", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    childSnapshot.ref.remove();
  });
}
```

Alternatively you can use `child_added` to remove the need for a loop:

```
var id = 42539660;
billref.orderByChild('eventid').equalTo(id).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.ref.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. I changed my logic to retrieve the firebase push id of the items that appear in the array and then use the push id to delete the node.