# How to delete data from firebase live database using id?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

I am trying to delete a record in firebase live database using this id.

[image]

My removeFromFavorites action takes in a recipe (with the id) and I want to match that with the record in the database and delete it.

```
export const removeFromFavorites = (recipe: RecipeConfig) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch
): Promise<void> => {
};
```

If this is not possible, can you please suggest an alternative, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To delete (or otherwise write to) a node from the database you must know its full path. If you don't know it's full path, you can determine that by first running a query, and then deleting the node/all nodes that match the query.

If `recipe` has an `id`, then that'd be something like this:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('favorites');
const query = ref.orderById().equalTo(recipe.id);
query.once('value').then((results) => {
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.ref.remove();
  });
});
```

Also see:

- [How to delete specific record in firebase having specified Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239209/how-to-delete-specific-record-in-firebase-having-specified-title/46239270#46239270)
- [Firebase - Delete a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690737/firebase-delete-a-node/38696768#38696768)
- [Firebase query and delete data in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034667/firebase-query-and-delete-data-in-javascript/51034694#51034694)

Comment: I tried your recommendation but I am getting a couple of errors on ref. orderById() and delete() does not exist on type reference.

Comment: I am also wondering if I can change the default key assigned by firebase to the recipe.id; that way, I can look for the recipe.id and delete accordingly.

Comment: I have a look at the links you attached, and the first one explained it perfectly, thanks.